# SQL Server : How to prevent Replication on Batch delete and allow on Daily basis delete operation?

Tags: sql-server, transactional-replication

I have a Transactional Replication running on SQL Server 2012. It replicates INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE.

Now im facing a condition (for DELETE Statement) where it forces us to :

1. Replicate only daily-basis DELETE Operation
2. DO NOT Replicate a Yearly-basis DELETE operation as we'd like to prune Data created < Current year

I suppose I can't use this (see image below) option for such conditon

[image]

What's a good way to achieve this ?

Comment: Can you please explain ?DO NOT Replicate a Yearly-basis DELETE (batch) operation

Comment: sorry images are blocked in my domain ,if image contains more details

Comment: @TheGameiswar its a batch DELETE operation. As we want only the data created this year (CURRENT year) exist on the Table, we must delete the data < this year. We will do it annually.

Comment: @TheGameiswar you may try this link for the image to work http://res.cloudinary.com/cepot/image/upload/v1456132692/WmIzD_ir6ahu.png

Comment: What is the real problem you are trying to solve? What do you mean a "batch delete" operation? Batching means you have several statements that you send as a single command. `BULK INSERT` operations deal with inserting a lot of data in a specialized way. None of these applies to `DELETE`, unless you mean `TRUNCATE` - a different command altogether. If by "batch" you mean "more than X rows", you are probably trying to solve an application problem using the wrong technique. There is *no* difference between deleting 10 or 10000 rows

Comment: @ngakak put `As we want only the data created this year (CURRENT year) exist on the Table, we must delete the data < this year. We will do it annually.` in the question itself. That the critical information - you aren't trying to prevent "batch deletes" (there's no such thing), you are trying to *prune* the source database without replicating the deletions. You could, eg. pause replication while pruning, then restart it

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks...I've updated the Question. its actually the same Delete operation. One executed as a daily opreation (Delete row A, B, C etc. the other one is Delete a bunch of data at once annually.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I was thinking the same, (eg. pause replication while pruning). is there any option to automate it ?

Comment: @ngakak Depends on what you mean by "automate". You can write the script you want to execute (pause repcliation, delete the data, restart replication) and run it using a SQL Server Job but this doesn't make much sense for something that happens once a year. Unless you want to hand-off the database to someone else that may not know about replication etc.

Answer (score 1):

The downvote was not warranted.  Here's your solution.

To *NOT* replicate the annual batch delete process, the assumption is that the delete process is being done inside some kind of stored procedure(s), correct? If so, what you do is enable "replicate execution of a stored procedure".  Once you enable this, you then create a post snapshot script that creates dummy versions of these stored procedures.  The stored proc is simply empty.  This way when it's executed on the publisher, only the proc call is replicated and executed on subscriber.  And since the proc is empty on the subscriber, nothing really happens.

If the yearly delete operation is *NOT* inside a stored proc, then you'll need to go back to development/operations team and tell them to put the archiving/maintenance call into a different stored proc so you can do the above.

Comment: Thank u for your suggestion,,,